# The term 'ant' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file , or operable program

Tags: touch, mobile

I am working on Salesforce Touch; I am new with this platform. 
I am referring to the Salesforce Touch guide. I am trying to create a native Android project, using this command

```
ant create_native -Dapp.name={DemoApp} -Dtarget.dir={C:\Anu Raj\project\Salesforce Touch} -Dpackage.name={com.acme.mobileapp}"
```

but i am getting this error while doing this --- > "

```
The term 'ant' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ ant <<<<  create_native -Dapp.name={DemoApp} -Dtarget.dir={C:\Anu Raj\project
\Salesforce Touch} -Dpackage.name={com.acme.mobileapp}
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ant:String) [], CommandNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

can anybody tell me what is the issue for this.

Comment: is apache ant installed? Did you correctly set your global variables? http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Comment: Please do not add random tags to your question. This has nothing to do with Force.com Sites, or Eclipse!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because its not able to find the ant executable in your Path.
I'm assuming you've installed Apache Ant. (http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

Assuming you're on Windows, you need to set your ANT_HOME and add the ant bin to your PATH environment variable

So My Computer > Proprties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables

Add a new Variable called ANT_HOME
Set the value to be the base directory of your apache ant installation, eg :

[image: ANT_HOME Environment Variable]

Then add the location of the ANT Bin directory to your PATH Variable, which will already exist.
eg : Add ;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin to the end of the PATH System Variable

[image: Set the ANT bin directory to your PATH Environment Variable]

After you've done this, you will need to launch a new command window and then ant can be used.

Even now, ant will work if you explicitly navigate to the Ant Installation's bin directory and type ANT.

Comment: thanks i did the same but i am getting this error when i run the Git shell - Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\srcloud\.ssh\id_rsa' because it does
not exist.
At C:\Users\srcloud\AppData\Local\GitHub\PoshGit_8d80d7433eabc8de6af51eeecef5be
a516df4997\GitUtils.ps1:249 char:32
+         $sshPath = Resolve-Path <<<<  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\srcloud\.ssh\id_rsa:St
   ring) [Resolve-Path], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Resol
   vePathCommand

Comment: That's not a problem related to Ant; that is Git not being able to find your private key so that you can connect to a source control repository. If you are unfamiliar with Git I suggest searching for a tutorial because that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys