# Force.com Migration tool Installation Process

Tags: force.com, migration, migration-tool

**Force.com Migration Tool:**

I am trying to install Force.com Migration tool which runs based on JDK & ANT.

I have successfully installed JDK1.6 & set an environment variable.
as described in the tutorial, I see the successful response in the console for Java -Version.

C:\Users\PRAX>java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)

I have tried installing Ant as well.
I have downloaded ant package from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
unzipped the content. tried to set the environment variable under the name "ANT_HOME".
it din work.
I tried executing, SET ANT_HOME = installation path --> ran in cmd prompt.
it worked. I checked by echoing it "echo %ANT_HOME%", it has fetched the correct path.

but, when I execute "ant" in cmd.. i don see any result.

C:\Users\PRAX>ant
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

can someone please explain how to set path or variable to make Migration tool work on my computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also new to add the Ant bin folder to your PATH environment variable in windows.

So Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables

You will find a variable called PATH. Append your ant bin directory to this variable.

Launch a new command window and then try.

I had answered this in more detail here, have a look it should sort you out hopefully.

[The term 'ant' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file , or operable program](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/the-term-ant-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-file/4388#4388)

Comment: Hi @Techtrekker, this time I followed the procedure you have put up. it worked fine. Thanks a lot for that. but, when I check the "ant" in the cmd prompt.. I see this result.C:\Users\PRAX>ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
some warning: "unable to locate".. would it affect application while using?

Comment: That seems like a java jre lib setup thing. Have you also copied the salesforce migration jar to your ant lib directory?

Answer (score -2):

We don't use force.com migration toolkit anymore. We use flosum, which is a great replacement for [changesets](http://www.flosum.com), ant scripts and [force.com migration toolkit](http://www.flosum.com).